# Which of the Stack Exchange sites should be used for Neural Network questions? Multiple ones seem to match

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The following sites seem to have something to do with Neural Networks, and most have questions on that subject:

- Stack Overflow
- Artificial Intelligence
- Computational Science
- Computer Science
- Cross Validated
- Data Science

How would one choose the appropriate one?

Comment: Could you please [edit] in more details about the question you intend to ask?

Comment: The FAQ now lists all those sites. I hope you'll be able to find the right site; if not, we'll need to see the question you want to ask.